# getting val from a 'jQuery Selectbox plugin 0.2' select box dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-selectbox

I recently posted about a problem I was having with not being about to ge the .val() from a selected dropdown.  The code was correct but something was preventing the on change from firing correctly.  I've narrowed the issue down and found when I remove the select box plugin it works as expected.
Can someone please help me get both to work, I'd like to keep select box on these dropdown && also write my own function that will pick up the selected value.

thanks.

Relevant code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select name="numberOfAdults" id="numberOfAdults" tabindex="2">
        <option>-Adults-</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

In script.js

```
//---------------------------------------------------
//------------------- Selectbox -------------------
//---------------------------------------------------
$(function () {
    $("#numberOfAdults").selectbox();
    $("#numberOfKids").selectbox();
    $("#eventAttending").selectbox();
});
```

mt script that doesn't give me the value, instead it will also give '-Adults- - -Adults-'

```
<script>
    $('#numberOfAdults').change(function() {
        var val1 = this.value;
        var val2 = $('#numberOfAdults option:selected').val();
        alert(val1 + " - " + val2);
    });
```

result:
[image]

Comment: The plugin probably creates a list instead of a select to make it stylable, so the `change` event doesn't fire, and the plugin probably has it's own events instead, meaning, read the fracking manual.

Comment: @adeneo, thanks for your valuable input

Comment: Really, it's right there, the `onChange` event, it even has an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$('#numberOfAdults').selectbox({
      onChange: function (val, inst) {
         alert(val);
      }        
});
```

#### Documentation: http://www.bulgaria-web-developers.com/projects/javascript/selectbox/

Comment: just literally tried      $('#numberOfAdults').selectbox({
            onChange: function() {
                var val1 = this.value;
                var val2 = $('#numberOfAdults option:selected').val();

                alert(val1 + " - " + val2);
            }
        }); but no joy, however, my params are none.

Comment: added params and worked perfectly, thank you for your help and time.

Comment: @SteveGreen, i'm glad to help :)